# JqGrid Search Panel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I m working on MVC 3 with JQGrid. I have created a Custom Search  Panel for the search instead of using the 'filterGrid' or 'filterToolbar'. I have a Users Action from which the JQGrid get filled. i created another Json Action which get the filtered result based on the parameter passed by 'Custom Search Panel'. The Json Action fired by Post method using jquery.

i want to know how to fill the JQGrid with the filtered data ? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to reload your grid with the standard method `myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');` and let it fetch the parameters needed by your action.
I would use just one action which receives all your filters:

```
public ActionResult Fetch(string param1, string param2, int param3, int page, int rows, string search, string sidx, string sord)
    {

    }
```

All you have to do is to define your filter in your jqGrid:

```
postData: {
            Param1: function() { return $("#param1").val(); },
            Param2: function() { return $("#param2").val(); }
            Param3: function() { return $("#param3").val(); }
        },
```

wrapping it in function.
Now, all you have to do is `myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');` and your jqGrid will fetch the data using your newly define filters.
You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275062/jqgrid-and-search-filter-best-way-to-repopulate-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819).
As always, Oleg has been great help in that.

Comment: i have tried this , it seems i m near to the solution but i m getting my filter values equal null when i m clicking search button .. any ideas why ?

Comment: i got 4 searching fields, so i have to create the combination of the fields, using IF statements in my repository class, which get so messy. any solution for this ?

Comment: @Saad:You can use different solutions.I guess your repository exposes IQueryable?! Personally I use nHibernate and combine Criterias. There's a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500972/linq-to-sql-how-to-efficiently-do-either-an-and-or-an-or-search-for-multiple-cr